# How to edit html in Visual FoxPro in Windows x64

Tags: webbrowser-control, activex, visual-foxpro

How to edit html in Microsoft Visual FoxPro application running under Windows x64

It seems that Microsoft Web Browser ActiveX is not avalaiblable in x84.

Maybe Internet Explorer x64 does not provide this ActiveX  to 32-bit Visual FoxPro application.
How to edit html  ?
Is there some html editor implemented in FoxPro or other solution ?

**Update**

Html editor is invoked as VFP form.
I tried to use Visual Foxpro html editor from

http://www.atoutfox.org/articles.asp?ACTION=FCONSULTER&ID=0000000027

which is also used in FoxyPreviewer

This form references Web Browser ActiveX control.

Running the form causes error that document is not an object.

Modifying the form shows that Web Browser control is not defined.

Application must run if copied to new vanilla Windows 7/8.1 x64 computer without installing.

Is it possible to distribute Web Browser ActiveX control with application and auto-register it if it
is not rewgister or create manifest which allows to use it ?
Or maybe there is html editor in FoxPro whixh does not require additional components?

Comment: More details please. Where is this HTML you want to edit, and I presume you mean change. E.g. Edit would be open the file in an editor and twiddle with it.

Comment: Hopefully a FoxPro boy will happen along then, never used it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041) ActiveX control is available in Windows 7 and 8 and 8.1, including both 32bit and 64bit Windows. That control is part of Windows Explorer and has been since [Windows 95](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_litigation#Anti-trust). So, you don't need to distribute it, install it, or register it.

On 64bit Windows, there is both a 32bit and 64bit ActiveX control. Since Visual FoxPro is exclusively 32bit, your code will always use the 32bit control, regardless of the bitness of your operating system.